# Default skins don't load

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

The mobs and the player itself only shows the head. Please help. I'm on a latest version of minecraft bedrock edition

Comment: Could you add some more information about your problem? For example: What platform are you on? When did the problem occur? Do you have any mods or custom texture packs loaded? You said the latest version; could you add the version of the game so the question ages better?

Comment: I downloaded minecraft on my phone 1.6.0.6 and it work smoothly but the problem is even steve dont have a body. Only the head is visible even to mobs. Im not using any mod or custom texture pack

Comment: This is a known, unsolved bug present in 1.6.0.6. [Link to the bug report.](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-34385) I would recommend re-installing the game, or waiting for the next patch.

Comment: But my cousin played 1.6.0.5 but still has the same issue but when other players play it works properly.

Comment: In the bug report I linked the problem is reported as occurring in 1.6.0.1, 1.6.0.5, 1.6.0.6. The bug is intermittent and unresolved. If you feel like it may be a different bug, then I would suggest opening a bug report on Mojang's site

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Minecraft, not your specific device. It is currently being tracked on Mojang's bug tracker as [MCPE-34385](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-34385). You can see in one of the many screenshots that only the head is shown, which leads me to believe this is the exact issue you're currently experiencing.

Right now the best thing to do is wait for a fix. You can also follow the bug for comments in case someone provides a workaround to the issue.